# How to check whether cursor in the middle of `read-multiple-choice` process

Tags: minibuffer, echo-area

Is there a way to check whether cursor is in the prompt of `read-multiple-choice`, waiting for user's response?

I have tried `(minibuffer-p)` and `(input-pending-p)`, but got no luck.

Code for testing (copy the code below to a new scratch-buffer and M-x eval-buffer RET):

```lisp
(defun test-prompt ()
  ;; check if running `read-multiple-choice' exists
  (unless (or (minibufferp) (input-pending-p))
    (error "Test failed. \n\
You are supposed to be in the middle of `read-multiple-choice'.")))

(run-with-idle-timer 1 nil #'test-prompt)

(read-multiple-choice
 "Prompt: Which prebuilt binary to download? "
 '((?1 "amd64-GNU/Linux"
       "GNU/Linux on Intel/AMD x86_64 CPU")
   (?2 "amd64-macOS"
       "macOS on Intel/AMD x86_64 CPU")
   (?q "quit")))
```

If `test-prompt` were able to detect a running `read-multiple-choice`, it shouldn't have errored out.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you report `(current-buffer)` you'll confirm that `(minibuffer-p)` should indeed be `nil`.

It does *look* like it's using the minibuffer, but if you check the code you'll see that `read-multiple-choice--short-answers` calls:

```
(let ((cursor-in-echo-area t))
  (read-event))
```

Which explains that misleading appearance.

Note also that the question can be asked/answered via GUI dialogue box (if the command was triggered by a mouse event); so the minibuffer wouldn't necessarily be relevant (in general) even if it was being used in the keyboard-based scenario.

`(input-pending-p)` isn't helpful to you at all.  That's non-nil if the user has provided an input which hasn't yet been processed.

Nothing is provided for your need, but you could always write advice to bind a dynamic variable around `read-multiple-choice`:

```el
(defvar my-read-multiple-choice-p nil
  "Non-nil when calling `read-multiple-choice'.")

(define-advice read-multiple-choice (:around (orig-fun &rest args) my-predicate)
  "Set `my-read-multiple-choice-p'."
  (let ((my-read-multiple-choice-p t))
    (apply orig-fun args)))
```

Comment: Ahh thanks! And I just realize that `cursor-in-echo-area` could be useful for check whether the cursor is around any prompts. Also, binding a dynamic variable helps to restrict the scope to specific event like `read-multiple-choice`, `completing-read`, etc.